# Decrypt file with mcrypt strange char's on end of file

Tags: php, delphi, delphi-xe3, mcrypt, rijndael

I've got a very strange problem with a self made function decryptfile. 
I want to decrypt a mp3 file which is encrypted with our own Delphi program.
After decrypting this songs with php the data is slightly different than decrypting it with Delphi. This results in difference in filesizes compared to Delphi and php. 
This is with every file we decrypt, so reading the last 578 bytes is not always the same.

An example of our result data:

```
Taginfo:filename: 180519: size: 7342031 bytes (Delphi decrypted)

TAGStolen danceMilky ChanceLICHTDICHT RECORDS#$#$2013000000100001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, 840900000000000010100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000


Taginfo:filename: 180519: size: 7342032 bytes (PHP decrypted)

AGStolen danceMilky ChanceLICHTDICHT RECORDS#$#$2013000000100001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, 8409000000000000101000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000T�8߂�j#���#6&

Difference in size: -1
```

You can see that the data is not equal and above that the PHP data is different on the end.

Here is my function:

```
require_once('mp3file.class.php'); 

function decryptfile($str){
    //read salt
    $salt = substr($str, 0, 8); //salt ok
    $str_out = substr($str, 8);  //encrypted data

    //read key
    $k = '';
    $bytes = array(*, *, *, *, *, *, *, *, *, *, *, *, *, *, *, *, *, *, *, *, *, *, *, *, *, *, *, *, *, *, *);        
    $string = "";
    foreach ($bytes as $chr) {
        $string .= chr($chr);
    }
    $key = $string;

    //fill hash
    $ctx = hash_init('sha512');
    hash_update($ctx, $salt);  
    hash_update($ctx, $key);
    $xkey = hash_final($ctx, true);

    //assing key
    $k = substr($xkey, 0, 32);

    //iv
    $iv = ''; 
    $size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $iv_array = array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    $string = "";
    foreach ($iv_array as $chr) {
        $iv .= chr($chr);
    }

    $str = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $k, $str_out, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,$iv);

    //$pad = ord($str[($len = strlen($str)) - 1]);

    return rtrim($str, "\0");
    //return substr($str, 0, strlen($str)-$pad);
}


    $farray = scandir('/var/www/html/test/in/');

    foreach ($farray as $item) {
        if (($item != '.') && ($item != '..')) {
            $filename = "test/in/".$item;
            $filename2 = "test/out/".$item;
            $filename2b = "test/out/".$item.".mp3";

            $enc = file_get_contents($filename);

            $jak = decryptfile($enc);

            $dec = fopen($filename2b, "w");
            fwrite($dec, $jak);
            fclose($dec);
            $strfile1 = "filename: " . $item . ': size: ' . filesize($filename2) . ' bytes (Delphi decrypted)<br>';
            $strfile2 = "filename: " . $item . ': size: ' . filesize($filename2b) . ' bytes (PHP decrypted)<br>';
            $v1 = filesize($filename2);
            $v2 = filesize($filename2b); 
            $v1 = $v1-$v2; 
            echo '<br>Taginfo:'. $strfile1. '<br>';
            $dec = file_get_contents($filename2);
            $dec2 = file_get_contents($filename2b);
            echo substr($dec, -578);
            echo '<br><br>';
            echo '<br>Taginfo:'. $strfile2. '<br>';
            echo substr($dec2, -578). '<br>';
            echo '<br>Difference in size: '.$v1 . '<br>';
            echo 'original header:<br>';
            $m = new mp3file($filename2);
            $a = $m->get_metadata();

            if ($a['Encoding']=='Unknown')
                $str = "?";
            else if ($a['Encoding']=='VBR')
                $str = print_r($a);
            else if ($a['Encoding']=='CBR')
                $str = print_r($a);
            unset($a);
            echo '<br><br>';
            echo 'decrypted header:<br>';
            $m = new mp3file($filename2b);
            $a = $m->get_metadata();

            if ($a['Encoding']=='Unknown')
                $str = "?";
            else if ($a['Encoding']=='VBR')
                $str = print_r($a);
            else if ($a['Encoding']=='CBR')
                $str = print_r($a);
            unset($a);
            echo '<br><br>';

        }
    }
exit;
```

Can someone explain me what here is the problem?

Comment: Why are you calling `rtrim`?

Comment: Because of ending char's. We've also used the padding. But that didn't help also.

Comment: That's not sufficiently detailed. What *specifically* are you expecting that call to `rtrim` to do and why are you doing it? What did you use padding for? And what happened when you used it? You are keeping all of your investigatory results from us. If you couldn't find the answer with an investigation, how are we supposed to without one?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz mayby I declared it not exactly as I wanted to. The problem is that, even without a $pad or trim the output data of our $str variable is not as it should be. We searched the internet for a solution of the difference in data. Some people told us that mcrypt adds padding data which should be removed. other people told us to remove the data by adding rtrim to the decrypted output. Hope it is much clearer now :)

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to use functions whose behavior you simply don't understand. Do you know what padding mcrypt adds? Do you have a plan for how the decryption code will know the original size of the file?

Comment: When we started porting our delphi code to PHP, we noticed the difference and from then on we started (due to lack of experience) on trying to find our solution on the internet. At this time we indeed know what padding does. But the strange fact is still there. Why is there a difference in filesize compared to input and output after only executing mcrypt_decrypt? Will it be easier to supply a link and some more info so you can see in real life?